# Running an application over ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

My girlfriend owns a tanning salon. Below is the image she views when she's putting people in a bed:

[image]

This image is taken off a software application called Tan Track. Is there anyway to somehow call or reference this software using a web application? The purpose would be so that other customers could view the information from home and see what beds are available, and perhaps see the que of the customers in line. Without getting the source code from Tan Track, would this be possible to do using ASP.NET?

Comment: Why don't you ask the [manufacturer](http://www.nichesoft.com)?

Comment: It looks like the application can produce many reports, including customers per date. You could export this on a regular basis, and write something that parses this and shows the number of beds available at a certain date and time. Not the most sophisticated of solutions, but it might be enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two possible options:

1. The application itself exposes an API that you can tap into.  (Highly unlikely)
2. If you have administrative rights to the database that it uses to store the underlying data, you can write any old web application you like against the database.  This may, however, be an illegal use of their software and a violation of licensing terms.

Most likely, the only ethical/legal method for providing the service is to contact the makers of the software and see if they provide an addon interface for customers, or if you are legally allowed to write one of your own.

**The legal/ethical way of doing it would be:**
(And remember, this is not legal advice.  I am not qualified to give legal advice.  You may also want to speak to a lawyer.)

Ask them **specifically** if you're allowed to write your own application using the data from their database and explain your reason for wanting to do so.

***IF they say it's allowed:***

Try to get it in writing.

You'd need to figure out what DB they are using, and code accordingly, but if you have legitimate access to the database, then yes, you can write any type of application you want to read and display the data.

It sounds like you may be newer to development, so I'd just caution you to be darn sure you know how to code securely (visit the [OWASP site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project), [familiarize yourself with the Microsoft SDL from their site](http://www.microsoft.com/security/sdl/default.aspx), and familiarize youeslf with [this older, but still incredibly relevant and useful guide to building secure ASP.NET websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649100.aspx) ***AND*** [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649874.aspx).) and that you understand what sensitive data is.  For example, showing the queue of customers in line would be OK if no names were used, but showing the names of customers might be a bad idea - they may not want it advertised that they're tanning on  your site, or may not want their abusive ex-boyfriend knowing when they can find them there, etc.

Really think through "what's the worst that could happen if my website were compromised - what could someone do with the data?"  That goes quadruple if you're storing customer's home address and 100 times if you're storing any sort of payment information.

Comment: I called Tan Track and they do not have any kind of open source API they will release and they certainly will not let me look at the source code (for obvious reasons). And yes, this is in fact a desktop application. I wasn't sure if their were any other ways around it, with somehow using ASP.NET or another form of web application development to reference it as a desktop application.

Comment: Edited to be more specific and helpful.  I also made a bit of an assumption with th last two paragraphs, forgive me if I'm wrong.

Comment: David, I appreciate the concerns and comments, as you hit the nail right on the head. I was planning on somehow changing the strings of raw data (first names, last names...etc) just to strings such as "2 Cusomters in line, 3 Customers in line...etc". My main concern is writing the application and seeing if this is actually possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible from a technical perspective. It's the ethical/legal perspective that's questionable.

Comment: Would I need the source code from tan track? This is where I get confused. If I don't have the source code, how am I suppose to incorporating the application with Tan Track?

Comment: No, you wouldn't.  You'd need to investigate and find out what database they use, and then connect to the ***database***, not the ***application***.  Once youy know how to connect to the database, as I said, you can just access it and write any sort of application to access the data.  The *program* is just the user inferface that provides access to the database (and likely business logic)  *You don't care about that*.  You'll be writing your own user interface.  You just want the data from the database.  Once you have that, the tutorials at www.asp.net should be sufficient to get you going.

Comment: So if the databse used is Microsoft SQL Server, you'd need to download SQL Server management Studio and explore the database.  if it's MS Access, open it with Access, etc.  You might be better off getting someone experienced to assist, actually.  It's possible to break something by mucking around in a databse you're not familiar with. Experience is a plus.  Paying an experienced developer may be a better use of time and money,

Comment: +1 for really going out of your way to help someone out.  Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Tan Track exposes a [web service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XML_Web_Services) (or something similar) that allows you to access their data, there is likely no (ethical) way to retrieve this information.  You would need to contact the vendor to see if they allow customers to access their application data for custom use.

It looks like that is a desktop application, so it seems unlikely that such an API would exist.

Answer (score 1):

If the application was written using a good pattern which seperated out the Business Logic from the Presentation logic, and it was written in C# then it should be possible to write your own ASP.net Web front end that emulates what you are seeing.

Sadly, this is rarely the case and will be more work than its worth to discover this.

On the up side, this application, from first glance, doesnt appear too complicated and should take you less time to write from scratch than to reverse engineer the dlls and how they work with the Presentation layer.

Edit: sorry, i made some bad assumptions, i thought you had access to the code. If you want to access this application over the web, there is a workaround...

You can setup remote desktop to run on the desktop at work so that you can access over the internet.

Comment: Did you read that he wants to provide the available beds from a website for customers to see from home?  Giving remote desktop access to customers is highly unlikely to be a viable solution.